# Bring window to front

Tags: javascript, html

How can I bring a non-active (means another window is in front of that page) to the front?
I've tried self.focus and window.focus, but it doesn't work...

I can't control the window in the front, because it's from a third-party plugin...

many thanks to every hint :)

Greetz,
Camillo

EDIT: Here the code I'm using on my site (that i'm trying to bring to front):

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Gallery</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.4.2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
   var timeFrame;
   $(function() { timeFrame=setInterval("lpcAuto();", 100);});
   function lpcAuto(){
     if ( $(document.activeElement).attr('id')=="lpcframe" ){

// HERE THE SNIPPET I'M SEARCHING :)

}
   }
</script>
```

Comment: Can you post the code you are using?

Comment: added to the main post (it's the code from the backgrond-page i want to bring to front). I Cant control the window that's in the front, because it's from a third party plugin :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you have to call blur() on the window that is on top. Then call focus() on the window that you want to call to the top.

Also note that browsers these days have popup blockers that prevent you from doing this, and you must disable these.

Comment: The problem is that i can't control the window that is in front :( Is there still a possibility for doing it only on the background-page?

Answer (score 1):

I performed the following test in Firefox 45 and wanted to share:

```
setTimeout(function(){window.focus()}, 2000);
```

a) Alt-tab to another window will bring the desired window to the front after 2s.

b) Minimizing the window will restore it and bring it to front after 2s.

c) Changing tabs will **not** let the tab re-gain focus.

d) Changing tabs and then Alt-tab to another window will **not** bring the first window to the front.